# Detect when app killed by user in background state iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, cocoa-touch

I am working in a chat application where I need to show user status (offline/online).
When my app is in foreground and background then I need to show user as online (managing by VoIP).
But when the user kill the app then it should go to offline.

I have to maintain a flag to show offline which I am managing in delegate function `applicationWillTerminate` but this function only called when app is in foreground state and user kill it by pressing double tap home button and swipe up.
This function does not get called when app is in background state. I mean simply press home by single tap (app will go in background) then again double tap to swipe up.

**Is there any function where I get 100% call either app is in background/foreground state and user kill the app?**

Answer (score 9):

> Is there any function where I get 100% call either app is in background/foreground state and user kill the app?

No. Just the opposite. If your app is terminated when already in the background, if it is suspended (ie not running in the background due to special entitlement), it is 100% certain you will get no event. You cannot. You are suspended and not running. The app dies in its sleep.

Comment: Leave the suspended state.

What about if you push your app in background and then immediately kill the app from background too (using double and swipe up). In this case your app was in background state before kill.
Then will you get a sure call in any delegate/function.

Comment: @matt is there any idea except (silent push notification) because my app doesn't use internet it will update health result in app.

Comment: Why? If it’s suspended there is nothing to update. You update when you are unsuspended.

Answer (score 0):

No, As per Apple Document

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate?language=objc

> For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case.

What you can do execute a method(which hit an API for keeping status online) after few seconds(whatever you find suitable time) when you app goes in Background, If method is calling successfully after that specific seconds then user stay online, if its not call after specified second then server update its status to offline. So It require both server and client handling.

Comment: Actually we have implemented **VoIP** (silent notification) to get callbacks and app sends ping (respond back to the server) in that delegate for background support.
I need to show offline only when app is killed properly from background too.
And even app is killed, it's getting callback so there is no way to avoid that ping until I will not set a flag to know whether app is terminated by user from background.